# copy cassandra sstable from gcloud to s3 with python

Tags: python, cassandra

I'm tasked with copying a few cassandra tables from our gcloud to athena using python
Right now the way everything works is that we have a script that download all of the files from gcloud then it runs sstabledump and we get this awful json that they try to convert to csv then have a script that goes over that csv and upload it to s3
so im looking for any way to improve it whether if its with a replacement for sstabledump that will turn it to csv instead or a package that turns that awful json dump to csv
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool called DSBulk (developed by DataStax) for loading and unloading of data from Cassandra (starting with Cassandra 2.1), and DSE (starting with DSE 4.7/4.8).  In simplest case, the command line looks as following:

```
dsbulk unload -k keyspace -t table -url path_to_unload
```

DSBulk is heavily optimized for loading/unloading operations, and has a lot of options, including import/export from/to compressed files, providing the custom queries, etc.

You can offload data as CSV or as JSON to the local machine, and then upload that files to the S3.

There is a series of blog posts about DSBulk, that could provide more information & examples: [1](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/03/datastax-bulk-loader-introduction-and-loading), [2](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/04/datastax-bulk-loader-more-loading), [3](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/04/datastax-bulk-loader-common-settings), [4](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/06/datastax-bulk-loader-unloading), [5](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/07/datastax-bulk-loader-counting), [6](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/12/datastax-bulk-loader-examples-loading-other-locations)

Comment: sadly this tool does not work for sstables ao its not good for what im looking for

Comment: you shouldn't work with SSTables, as they may contain only partial updates of the rows, not the full row...

Comment: my employer have tried to get the info directly from the db but it was slow and the db couldnt handle all of the load so they decided to use sstable
because we want to use something that would run automatically every few hours to update the table